# Print to fax with multiple documents on HP inkjet

Tags: drivers, printer, fax

I have an HP OfficeJet Pro printer, and for faxes I use the HP Universal Fax Driver, on Windows 10. I want to send a fax through the print-to-fax function, with multiple attachments. How to do that?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying it's already faxing. So what's your question? Also, most systems cannot handle multiple discrete files (which is what attachments are) for a single fax job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

As I understand it (without testing), "Windows Fax and Scan" is able to send faxes with attachments. When you create a fax, attachments can be added by clicking the Paper Clip. To run it, just type "Windows Fax and Scan" into Cortana. However, it expects the PC to be connected to the phone via a modem, so it does not use a printer. There are fax modems that plug into a USB port - search "fax modem"

My original answer below only applies to faxing via a printer.

If I understand you correctly, the answer to your question is the same as to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1515739/linux-lp-command-print-both-sides-on-multiple-files): it cannot be done. Each attachment is a different print job, and the printer cannot combine them.

The only way to do what you want is to combine all the attachments into 1 document. If they are of different types, print all of them to PDF, and combine the PDFs with PDFTKBuilder, as I mentioned in the other question.

Comment: Thanks for answers. The linux driver, HPLIP, can handle multiple attachments when running a print-to-fax job. So I thought maybe I am just missing something with the Windows driver.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you a solution that bypasses the printer.